# Does length of ID matter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some trouble with getting an element by id. My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="F6fsCKVqdAXAXUlRAAAC0zwj8s9QQUKp0riVAAAD"></div>
<li class="active" id="F6fsCKVqdAXAXUlRAAAC0zwj8s9QQUKp0riVAAAD"></li>
```

When I use an ID like this, I only get the li element. [Picture of result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU2S5.png)

But when I try with another, shorter id - like this:

```
<div id="room1"></div>
<li class="active" id="room1"></li>
```

Then I get both elements.  [Picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9nf0.png)

I don't understand this behaviour, someone care to explain?

Comment: only one `id` is allowed - same multiple `id`s are not allowed...

Comment: Never have two elements with the same id. This is illegal to Dom, but only jquery strangely accept this.

Comment: Where is the ul or ol that the li has to be inside?

Comment: This is just snippets of my code, I did not include everything.

Comment: I have seen MS aspx pages generate ids longer than that

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in that it must be at least one char. There is no Max.

From the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> 3.2.3.1 The id attribute
>
> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.
>
> An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes,
>   most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using
>   fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element when scripting,
>   and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.
>
> If the value is not the empty string, user agents must associate the
>   element with the given value (exactly, including any space characters)
>   for the purposes of ID matching within the element's home subtree
>   (e.g. for selectors in CSS or for the getElementById() method in the
>   DOM).
>
> Identifiers are opaque strings. Particular meanings should not be
>   derived from the value of the id attribute.
>
> This specification doesn't preclude an element having multiple IDs, if
>   other mechanisms (e.g. DOM Core methods) can set an element's ID in a
>   way that doesn't conflict with the id attribute.
>
> The id IDL attribute must reflect the id content attribute.

Answer (score 1):

An [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), like the name suggests, must be the unique across the HTML document.

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document

An alternative would be using a different ID to represent your `li` element or  a class, like you used for representing the `active` state.

Comment: A class would be better, I agree. I'll change that. But the problem is not that my ID is not unique, as you can see in the second picture.